# cannot load such file -- phantomjs/poltergeist (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

[image]I'm currently having trouble with phantomjs. I have done `brew install phantomjs` and `gem install phantomjs`. When starting the app with `rails s` I'm promted with this `cannot load such file -- phantomjs/poltergeist (LoadError)`

[image]

Comment: Gemfile and stack trace?

Comment: I just added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

```
1. git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
2. cd phantomjs
3. git checkout 1.9
4. ./build.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I still get the same error after following your steps.

Comment: @gentlyawesome how you add phantom in your app?

Comment: `brew install phantomjs'

Comment: @gentlyawesome cmon, I mean your >>RUBY CODE<<